# How to call Tasks synchronously, in a functional fluent style?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, functional-programming, task, synchronous

Suppose I have an asynchronous method...

```
public async string MyAsyncMethod() { return await AnyLongRunOperation(); }
```

And a I have a generic method to call asynchronous methods synchronously:

```
public static TResult CallSynchronously<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> Operation)
{
    var CallingTask = Task.Run(() => Operation());
    CallingTask.Wait();

    return CallingTask.Result;
}
```

Then the call can be made as (which works fine):

```
string ResultMessage = CallSynchronously(() => MyAsyncMethod());
```

But if I want to convert that method in an extension method to call it in a functional fluent style (so to avoid to pass a lambda as parameter), then I tryed with this...

```
public static TResult CallSynchronously<TResult>(this Task<TResult> Operation)
{
    var CallingTask = Task.Run(() => Operation.Result);
    CallingTask.Wait();

    return CallingTask.Result;
}
```

So now I can call it like...

```
var Result = MyAsyncMethod().CallSynchronously();
```

But here is the problem: It hangs!

So, question is: How to call Tasks synchronously in a functional fluent style?

Answer (score 1):

As Frank mentioned, you're probably seeing a deadlock that I [describe in full on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). The difference between these code blocks:

```
string ResultMessage = CallSynchronously(() => MyAsyncMethod());
```

and:

```
var Result = MyAsyncMethod().CallSynchronously();
```

is the context in which `MyAsyncMethod` is invoked. In the first one, it is invoked in a thread pool context (within the `Task.Run`). In the second one, it is invoked directly. Presumably this is in on a UI thread, so any `await`s in `MyAsyncMethod` will capture the UI context and attempt to resume the method on that context. Meanwhile, `CallSynchronously` is blocking the UI thread, causing the deadlock.

The real problem is here:

> I have a generic method to call asynchronous methods synchronously

There are extremely rare situations where it is acceptable to call asynchronous methods synchronously (BTW, there is **no** use case I can think of to do this *on a UI thread*). It certainly should not be a *common* scenario. It should *certainly* not be common enough to have a utility method just for that purpose. Just the existence of this method indicates that there's something seriously wrong with the design of the application.

Instead of trying to hack together synchronous-over-asynchronous code, just embrace async:

```
var Result = await MyAsyncMethod();
```

Comment: I'll give you a case: You have an intermediate web service, which depends on other web services to compute a result. I.e.: asynchrony is not always possible.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but the question is not 'why' it hangs, but 'how' to call it fluently (functional style) without hanging.

Comment: @NéstorSánchezA.: In your use case, just make the intermediate web service asynchronous. There is no way to this fluent unless you first wrap it (e.g., `Fluent(MyAsyncMethod).CallSynchronously()`).